# WCF web service fail run from the IIS because could not load DLL?

Tags: wcf

I wrote some WCF application.
I registered the application on the IIS.

The WCF application is build by using some dll that i wrote in the past. 
I created reference to them and its seems that all work fine when i start the application thru the visual studio 2010.

But when i run it thru the IIS - i get message about some DLL that missing - even if the DLL it clearly in the project.

What i can do to fix it ? 
I remove the reference - and load it again - and still nothing help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the DLL/Reference marked as Copy Always in properties?  This will force the DLL to copy to the bin folder which IIS will require for a non-GAC'd assembly